# Python testing if whitespace(\s) symbol is in string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a problem testing if "\s" symbols are present in a string. For example is `'\sgoogle\s.com'` must show that there is.

Comment: Are you trying to match actual whitespace, or a backslash followed by an s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# use raw strings to ignore escapes:
s = r'\sgoogle\s'
print s, s.find(r'\s') != -1

# and with regex:
import re
print re.search(r'\\s', s)
```

*Gives:*

```
\sgoogle\s True
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f2d696fc850>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your `\` as follows:

```
s = '\sgoogle\s.com'
re.search(r'(\\s)', s)
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/tF9oW6